# why package in my java project does not compile when grails project run as grails-app,there java project is referenced to grails project

Tags: java, class, grails, web, reference

These are images about two my project:
java project include: many package xyz.
grails project, I reference to java project by two way:

- Add in java build path.
- Check in project reference.

So I have file `TestsimiliraDetection.java` in grails project. It calls all packages in java project.

When I run `TestsimiliraDetection.java` as java-aplication, it does not matter. But when I run ThirdGrails project as grails app, it produces the following error:

```
Compiling 3 source files  [groovyc] org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
  [groovyc] Compile error during compilation with javac.
  [groovyc] A:\juno-workspace\ThirdGrails\src\java\readInput\TestSimitaryDetection.java:7: error: package local.extractText.extractText does not exist
  [groovyc] import local.extractText.extractText.ExtractPdf;
  [groovyc]                                     ^
  [groovyc] A:\juno-workspace\ThirdGrails\src\java\readInput\TestSimitaryDetection.java:8: error: package local.extractText.extractText does not exist
  [groovyc] import local.extractText.extractText.GetSection;
  [groovyc]                                     ^
  [groovyc] A:\juno-workspace\ThirdGrails\src\java\readInput\TestSimitaryDetection.java:9: error: package local.extractText.extractText does not exist
  [groovyc] import local.extractText.extractText.GetStructureOfFile;
  [groovyc]                                     ^
  [groovyc] A:\juno-workspace\ThirdGrails\src\java\readInput\TestSimitaryDetection.java:10: error: package local.extractText.getPositionPdf does not exist
  [groovyc] import local.extractText.getPositionPdf.Page;
  [groovyc]                                        ^
  [groovyc] A:\juno-workspace\ThirdGrails\src\java\readInput\TestSimitaryDetection.java:11: error: package local.extractText.getPositionPdf does not exist
  [groovyc] import local.extractText.getPositionPdf.Paragraph;
  [groovyc]                                        ^
  [groovyc] A:\juno-workspace\ThirdGrails\src\java\readInput\TestSimitaryDetection.java:12: error: package local.extractText.getPositionPdf does not exist
  [groovyc] import local.extractText.getPositionPdf.Part;
  [groovyc]                                        ^
  [groovyc] A:\juno-workspace\ThirdGrails\src\java\readInput\TestSimitaryDetection.java:13: error: package local.extractText.getPositionPdf does not exist
  [groovyc] import local.extractText.getPositionPdf.Section;
  [groovyc]                                        ^
  [groovyc] A:\juno-workspace\ThirdGrails\src\java\readInput\TestSimitaryDetection.java:14: error: package local.infoFile does not exist
  [groovyc] import local.infoFile.infoThesis;
  [groovyc]                      ^
  [groovyc] A:\juno-workspace\ThirdGrails\src\java\readInput\TestSimitaryDetection.java:15: error: package local.libs does not exist
  [groovyc] import local.libs.Lib;
  [groovyc]                  ^
  [groovyc] A:\juno-workspace\ThirdGrails\src\java\readInput\TestSimitaryDetection.java:16: error: package local.lucene does not exist
  [groovyc] import local.lucene.FindCopy;
.......
```

Here package xyz not found .xyz is package in my java-project.
But it doesn't work. Is there a way to reference those projects? Why don't those packages compile? I also added class folder in java build path of grails project, but it still produces an error.
Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to add your Java code directly to Grails project you need to follow the standard classpath rule. In Grails you have this `src/java` folder which is the root classpath for any Java code you would like to put into your project. Then if you import class like `local.lucene.FindCopy`, the file `src/java/local/lucene/FindCopy.java` has to exist.

Remember that Grails command like `run-app` doesn't care about what you set in your Eclipse project build path. It only indicates the behavior of your IDE, but not Grails itself. But if you use e.g. GGTS (Groovy Grails Tool Suite), build path in `src/java` should be defined by default for any Java project.

### Alternative solution

Consider also providing your Java dependencies as a maven artifacts. Basically if you put your Java code into the Maven project, you can simply add the dependency that will come from your local maven repository. It is widely described in the documentation - http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/2.3.x/guide/conf.html#dependencyResolution It's worth trying.

Comment: I don't wan't add packages in java project into src/java of grails project.
Because therefore i need to re-import many library jar in grails project.and reconfigure grails project . it's not happy.

Comment: Got your point. Maven dependency will fit best your needs. It will cover any other dependent library and will keep your Grails project clean from any unrelated files.